# Set Up Scope Using Grant Type Password in Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the following code to get accesstoken by using grant type password. I am able to get the token but the scope that I am setting up here is not returning in the resopnse. here i set up scope as **Group.ReadWrite.All** but all the time i am getting response with scope **Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared email offline_access openid profile User.Read** . What is wrong here and how I can setup scope from here?

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "XXXXXXXX"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "XXXXXXXX"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id",  "XXXXXXXXXXX"),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"),
                   new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope","Group.ReadWrite.All")

                });
                    string url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token";
                    var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                    string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return resultContent;
                }
```

Comment: Have you considered using the MSAL SDK rather than trying to hand roll your auth flow?

Comment: The MSAL SDK is here https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet